# Accessing element at index in tensor

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensor, loss-function

I am trying to build a custom loss function in Keras. 
My model is an image colorization CNN, and the idea is to penalize each predicted pixel based on it's rarity in a previously measured pixel color distribution over my dataset.
Loss function gets pre-computed ratios of each color value to the total amount of pixels from a distribution. 
So I have to get the coefficient for each true pixel, which has to be accessed in the ratios array at index of current pixel value.

I have built "dumb" loss version in NumPy, and it works as supposed.
As I am trying to convert it to Tensorflow with [tf.map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) I am seeing no way to implement that. My tries of running a sessions or evaluating a tensor fail.

Below is presented my loss function.

```
def color_rebalancing_loss(ratios):

    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        err = np.absolute(np.subtract(y_true, y_pred))
        pixel_weight = tf.map_fn(lambda x: coefficient(x), y_true)
        return err * pixel_weight

    def coefficient(x):
        x = tf.to_int32(x)
        x = x.eval(session = tf.Session())
        return 1/ratios[x]

    return loss
```

It fails on this line,

```
    x = x.eval(session = tf.Session())
```

With this error:

```
    ValueError: Operation 'loss/activation_1_loss/map/while/TensorArrayReadV3' has been marked as not fetchable.
```

My search over the internet did not reveal any potential fixes, people suggest do not iterate over the array, use buit-in tensorflow function, but accessing

```
   ratios[x]
```

is a must in this case. 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please describe what is the loss function that you are trying to implement? (mathematically, that is) Your code is mixing NumPy and TensorFlow operations, which is probably not right, and it is most likely possible to do what you need without `tf.map_fn`, but even if you use it you should not try to evaluate the tensor there.

Comment: Also what is `ratios`? I think what you may want is something like `tf.absolute(y_true - y_pred) / tf.gather(ratios, tf.to_int32(y_true))`...

Comment: Yes, `tf.gather(ratios, tf.to_int32(y_true))` was what I was looking for. Thanks